# How can i save results in different column in a dataframe in python?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, calculated-columns

I have to compare a columns with all other columns in the dataframe. The column that i have to compare with others is located in position 4 so i write df.iloc[x,4] to take column values. Then i have to consider these values, multiply them with the values in the next column (for example df.iloc[x,5]), create a new column in the dataframe and save results. Then i have to repeat this procedure to the end the existing column (the original dataframe has 43 column, so the end it is the df.iloc[x,43] )
How can i do this in python? 
If it is possibile can you do some examples? I try to put my code in the post but i 'm not good with my new phone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) - compare filtered `DataFrame` with column `E` in position `4`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,8,9],
                   'G':[1,3,5],
                   'H':[5,3,6],
                   'I':[7,4,3]})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I
0  1  4  7  1  5  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  9  5  6  3

print (df.iloc[:,5:].eq(df.iloc[:,4], axis=0))
       F      G     H      I
0  False  False  True  False
1  False   True  True  False
2  False  False  True  False
```

If need multiple by column in position `4` use [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html):

```
print (df.iloc[:,5:].mul(df.iloc[:,4], axis=0))
    F   G   H   I
0  35   5  25  35
1  24   9   9  12
2  54  30  36  18
```

Or if need multiple by shifted columns:

```
print (df.iloc[:,4:].mul(df.iloc[:,5:], axis=0, fill_value=1))
     E   F   G   H   I
0  5.0  49   1  25  49
1  3.0  64   9   9  16
2  6.0  81  25  36   9
```